# Delphi 10.2 - слишком длинный строковый параметр

Tags: delphi, ms-word

Есть DLL, которая находит текст в *MSWord*, и вставляет вместо него свой (работало все – на ура).
Но с некоторых пор

```
function FindAndPasteTextDoc(AFindText, APasteText: widestring;
                             AUnderLine, ABold, AItalic, ACountReplace: integer;
                             AColor: olevariant):boolean; export;
begin
  StartOfDoc;
showmessage('');
  FindAndPasteTextDoc := true;
  try
    TypeDos_Templs.Selection.Find.Text := AFindText;
    TypeDos_Templs.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text := APasteText;
    TypeDos_Templs.Selection.Find.Forward := True; 
…
if ACountReplace = 1 then
      TypeDos_Templs.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace := wdReplaceOne)
    else TypeDos_Templs.Selection.Find.Execute(Replace := wdReplaceAll);
  except
    FindAndPasteTextDoc := false;
```

На строке

```
TypeDos_Templs.Selection.Find.Replacement.Text := APasteText;
```

Если «APasteText» длиной более 255 символов ошибка

> … exception class EOleException with message 'Слишком длинный
>   строковый параметр'.

Ранее было

> APasteText: string

Но как видно «*widestring*» тоже не слишком помог

Как исправить ошибку?

P.S.
Вызов функции:

```
function FindAndPasteTextDoc(AFindText, APasteText: widestring;
                               AUnderLine, ABold, AItalic, ACountReplace: integer;
                               AColor: olevariant):boolean; far; external 'SPF';
```

Comment: можно конечно "*APasteText*" сразу проверять на длину и если она больше чем 255 символов, то разбивать ее на части например по 250 символов, и вставлять частями, конечно у каждой части (кроме последней) в конце дложна быть метка, по которой можно будет ее находить для вставки следующей части.

Но как-то громоздко это...

Comment: судя по https://stackoverflow.com/a/5051064/4908529 (увы - без ссылок на документацию, сам тоже в доках не нашел про ограничения длины) - именно так и придется поступить.

Comment: предлагают еще вот такой вариант wordexpert.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1122